# UML use case diagram for cinema equipment retailer

Tags: database, uml

I have been given the following scenario :

HyperAV is a retailer of home cinema equipment. They sell a variety of products including televisions, speakers, amplifiers, Blu-ray/DVD players and cables. The company has its head office in Stockport and 5 retail branches around the UK (in London, York, Cardiff, Manchester and Newcastle) and a large warehouse in Birmingham.

Due to the specialised nature of the products most sales are made in the shops which also have demonstration facilities allowing staff to show off the products to customers before they buy. However, the shops can also take orders over the telephone. The company deals with a number of suppliers who deliver items to both the shops and the warehouse. Limited space is available in the shops, so large numbers of items are stored at the warehouse and sent to the shops when their stock runs low.

The company’s buyer and stock controller are based in Stockport and work together to ensure that each branch has an adequate stock level of fast-selling items. If a shop takes an order for a product that it does not hold in stock, payment is taken and the item is sent to the shop from the warehouse. If the warehouse does not have a product in stock, it is ordered from the supplier by the buyer.

From this scenario I have been asked to draw a use case diagram.
[image: hyper av ucd]
I have received feedback but only to an extent where I have been told it is slightly incorrect. I would like to know if anyone can see what is wrong with it or how i can improve it in anyway?

Answer (score 1):

I will not go and analyze what is right/wrong with your business case, but here are a few remarks:

- Do not use Generalization with UCs. Each UC shall be a unique added value the system under consideration (SUC) delivers to the actor. If you have Generalization this means your UC is not unique. E.g. `Deliver product`: these are two absolutely separate UCs. They use a delivery service. But that's a UC for another SUC (namely the delivery service).
- Avoid the use of `<<include>>/<<extend>>` as they indicate the use of functional analysis. UCs are about synthesis which is the opposite of that.
- Use verb-substantive to name your UC. `Order` for example is not a UC.
- Think about the "use" in UC. What is the added value it returns to its actor? If that is not of a real use, it's not UC. `Process payment` is an administrative task, not a UC. So what is the use behind this?

Comment: Thomas, I'm not following you here.  Why wouldn't you ever use Generalization with UC's or includes and extends, given that they are all part of the spec?

Comment: @BobRodes The fact that the spec does allow it is not a sign that it's of good use. Language allows to create syntactical correct sentences without semantics.

Comment: Of course, but why do you think that these features are never useful?  Presumably, the creators of the spec don't agree with you, or they wouldn't have gone to the trouble of including them.

Comment: @BobRodes applying a generalization pattern implies some sort of cloning which contradicts the pattern of uniqueness.

Comment: To me, generalization says that two different use cases have things in common, and things not in common.  An example given in the spec is a "Perform ATM Transaction" use case, with "Withdraw", "Transfer Funds", and "Deposit Funds" all inheriting from it.  Each of the specialized use cases performs a transaction, but each transaction type is different.  Furthermore, applying a generalization/specialization pattern could imply reuse rather than cloning, couldn't it?

Comment: @BobRodes Sorry to say, but that is nonsense. If they have things in common than that is the common sense and vulgo the basic use case. While generalization can make sense with classes, it does not make sense with use cases. Again, trying to apply generalization is also a sign of applying functional analysis. This is not about use case synthesis at all!

Comment: I'm not seeing your point.  I agree that if they have things in common that is the basic use case.  Why can't the basic use case have multiple specializations that are themselves use cases?  Your point that this is a "sign of applying functional analysis" is a point, but it seems to me that the process of dividing a system into use cases is per se an application of functional analysis as well, albeit a very light one.

Comment: @BobRodes Actually no. It took me quite long to get that, but UC are about synthesis. This is putting pieces together (by asking around picking the Lego stones and construct some raw system basics). Later after the UC synthesis phase you will go and disassemble it to find things in common. But that will be when building the class model.

Comment: I think we might just disagree then, although I will think about what you have said.  But, can you explain why you don't find extensions and inclusions to be a valid part of a use case diagram either?

Comment: @BobRodes For the very same reason. In almost all cases you are using functional decomposition when applying them. Each UC must be complete in itself with a full add value for its actor. So I/E is superfluous. If you need to somehow add ordering you can do that with constraints.

Comment: So, you are saying, for example, that the use case "Perform ATM Transaction" should not optionally have the use case "Get online help", to take the example from the spec for extensions.  How would you document the optional online help UC, or are you saying that it is not useful in a UCD context to document it at all?

Comment: @BobRodes You don't get it. UCs are not about the order of added value. They are about having added value at all. "Perform Transaction" is an administrative task, not an added value. "Withdraw money" is a UC. "Offer help" is also a UC.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that I'm implying that UCs are about the "order of added value."  In fact, I completely agree that UCs are not intended to diagram the order in which behaviors occur in a system.  I'm just taking examples directly from the spec, and asking you to explain your position relative to these.  So, I'll rephrase and sharpen my question, using your semantics instead of theirs.  You are saying, for example, that the use case "Withdraw money" should not be extended by the use case "Offer help".  How would you document the "Offer help" UC, if at all?

Comment: @BobRodes You may add an extension point to the UC. But basically I think it's irrelevant. The point is to show that there IS added value. Whether you use the help inside withdraw or not does not matter as long as you show there are both UCs. Honestly, I don't think that the OMG guys did a good job with UCs at all. They are too techie and lack the business aspect. This is why there is so much confusion around use cases.

Comment: Ok, now I understand your point.  Thanks for your persistence.  :) My typical consumer of a UCD is a stakeholder, who is typically well versed in the business aspects of the problem domain, and typically not at all so in the technical ones.  If I can't explain a UCD in a half hour to a stakeholder who has never seen one before, then I need to simplify it.  If an include or extend facilitates that purpose, then its value is self-evident to me. I find that I use them occasionally, and can't remember using a specialization outside of a teaching environment.

Comment: @BobRodes Yep. Bridging between business and techie guys is one of those fragile connection points that tend to break projects.  Those doing a good job are commonly used to have a set of red ears and noses from the punches getting from both sides. ;-)

Comment: Very true.  Seems like you and I have come to the same practical understanding by rather different theoretical paths.  :)  FWIW, I see the "Lego brick synthesis" that you describe as the means of defining the entire system, and use cases as a means of disassembling the system to find units of behavior.

Comment: @BobRodes So to say, though I would not use "disassembling" in the context of use cases. The key is synthesis. You look into your Lego box and find which parts match to build the system under consideration. They identify the UCs and from them you build separate piles (each pile is then useful in its way). Then in the later phase you inspect the single piles and disassemble units for details. But in the beginning there is - synthesis! This is the main issue that people start with analysis rather than synthesis.

Comment: I see it as synthesizing the entire system from its artifacts, and then breaking the system into units of behavior, the use cases.

Comment: @BobRodes That sounds ok :-)